# Bulk API queue and REST API actions, any way to ensure sequence?

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

I have an app that perform some bulk operations but also requires real time updates for single records.
I was thinking if there is a way to ensure that once the bulk action has been queued, any REST action done after that (on one record also present in the bulk action) will happen after the bulk action.

Currently, the only ways I found are:

1. Use always Bulk API, even for single records. This has the downside that sometime it's not really real-time, but it handles everything as a queue.
2. Wait for Bulk API request to end before performing any REST action, this however is like using always the bulk api
3. Create some sort of queue on my side which ensure rest actions will be performed only after a bulk is completed, this has the advantage of having full control, but requires much more work

Any other suggestion?